# R: "caught segfault" when running cox proportional hazards model

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, coredump, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am running several Cox models, each time adding one new variable.

The primary model I ran was

```
model1 <- coxph(Surv(time1sec, time2sec, event) ~ gain + Buy + Lev + TP + gain:TP + SL + gain:SL + InstrumentID, data)
```

This worked fine, but then I wanted to add a `week` fixed effect to take into account the time (or week) in which a trade was opened. So I ran the following:

```
model2 <- coxph(Surv(time1sec, time2sec, event) ~ gain + Buy + Lev + TP + gain:TP + SL + gain:SL + InstrumentID + week, data)
```

When I run this model on my laptop, R crashes. When I run it on the cluster, I get the following error:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0xfffffffc00000000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: docount(y, x, weight)
 2: survConcordance.fit(y, lp, strata, weights)
 3: fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,     method = method, row.names(mf))
 4: coxph(Surv(time1sec, time2sec, event) ~ gain + Buy + Lev + TP + gain:TP + SL + gain:SL + InstrumentID + week, data)
aborting ...
/var/spool/gridscheduler/execd/node074/job_scripts/27524: line 28: 37078     Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

For model1 I used 8GB of RAM and it worked fine, for model2 I tried increasing it to 128 GB on the cluster but it did not work.

I am guessing it doesn't have to do with memory but instead with me adding the `week` variable. Is this error occurring because the week variable is correlated in some way to `time1sec` and `time2sec`, which are the open and close dates of the trade?

**UPDATE**
I plotted `week` against the `time1sec` as shown in the graph. I know that these two variables are perfectly correlated, but my question is since the duration is also based on time2sec, can't I include week as a fixed effect? Or is this taken into account by the model via the time1sec variable?

[image: plot-openWeek-vs-time1sec]

Comment: Hello! I know this is an old question, but have you found a way to resolve this issue? I am encountering similar problem with a cox regression in python scikit-survival package. Adding certain variables seem to cause python to crash, with "segmentation fault" error. No idea how to resolve it.